# Adding values to a specific key position in PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, string, web

I'm using a library that takes, amongst other parameters, an array of names and create a `<select>` combobox containing the `<option>` elements named after what was in that array. It also assigns to the `value` attribute of the `<option>` nodes the value of the index at which the name was taken. So, for example, if the index 0 of an array contained "foo", then it would create a tag like follows: `<option value="0">foo</option>`. For reference, here is the code for that library:

```
function generateSelect(objDimensionAssoc, obj, select_name, label_name, function_name, state, DivAlignement)
{
    //Valid object before
    sChaine = "";
    if(  (obj != null) && (obj != undefined) && (obj != "") && (parseInt(countObject(obj)) > 0) ){
        if( state == 'show' ){

            sChaine +="<label for='"+select_name+"' ><span>"+label_name+"</span></label>\n";
            sChaine +="<div class='"+DivAlignement+"'>\n";
            if(function_name != "")
                sChaine +="<select name='"+select_name+"' id='"+select_name+"' onchange='"+function_name+"' >\n";
            else
                sChaine +="<select name='"+select_name+"' id='"+select_name+"'>\n";

            //lang = variable reconnu dans tout les pages

            for (var x=0; x < obj.length; x++){
                //One or two domentionnal array
                if(obj[x] != null){
                    if(objDimensionAssoc == "1"){
                        if(chaineUrl){
                            sChaine += compare_and_create( x, obj[x], chaineUrl[select_name], select_name);
                        } else {
                            sChaine += compare_and_create( x, obj[x], "", select_name);
                        }
                    } else { 
                        if(chaineUrl){  
                            sChaine += compare_and_create( x, obj[x][lang], chaineUrl[select_name], select_name);
                        } else {
                            sChaine += compare_and_create( x, obj[x][lang], "", select_name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            sChaine +="</select>\n";
            sChaine +="</div>\n";

        }
        return(sChaine);
    } else {
        //empty array
        if( state == 'show' ){
            sChaine +="<label for='"+select_name+"' ><span>"+label_name+"</span></label>\n";
            sChaine +="<div class='"+DivAlignement+"'>\n";
            sChaine +="<select name='"+select_name+"' id='"+select_name+"' disabled='true' >\n";
            sChaine +="<option value='0'>&nbsp;</option>\n";
            sChaine +="</select>\n";
            sChaine +="</div>\n";
        }
        return(sChaine);
    }
}

function compare_and_create( key, innerText, string_compare,select_name)
{
    if(key == string_compare){
        return ("<option value='"+key+"' selected='selected'>"+innerText+"</option>\n");
    } else {
        return ("<option value='"+key+"'>"+innerText+"</option>\n");
    }
}
```

Here is where I call it:

```
myDiv = document.getElementById('tmp_stationDiv');
var stationsList = new Array();
stationsList = JSON.parse(<?php getStationList($regions); ?>);
myDiv.innerHTML = generateSelect("1",stationsList,
                            "slt_idStations",message["txt_choose_station"][lang],
                            '','show','blockDiv');
```

And this is the code of the function `getStationList()`:

```
function getStationList($regions)
{
    $slt_nomStations = (isset($_GET["slt_nomStations"]) ? $_GET["slt_nomStations"] : 0);;
    $db = ConnectionFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT S.station_id, S.name, SA.sub_area_name FROM dev.Station AS S INNER JOIN dbo.SubArea AS SA ON S.sub_area_id = SA.sub_area_id INNER JOIN data.MonthlyNormalData as MND ON MND.station_id = S.station_id WHERE sub_area_name = '$regions[$slt_nomStations]' AND value IS NOT NULL ORDER BY S.name ASC");
    $stmt->execute();

    $stations = array();
    $lastStationName = "";
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
        if ($lastStationName != $row['name'])
        {
            array_push($stations, $row['name']);
            $lastStationName = $row['name'];
        }
    }

    $newJSArray = json_encode($stations);
    echo json_encode($newJSArray);
}
```

Now this works perfectly fine. The output of `getStationList()` is, for example, `"[\"LA GRANDE RIVIERE A\"]"` and I then use `JSON.parse()` to transform that into a javascript array.

Unfortunately, the `value` associated with the `<option>` node will be 0, 1, 2, ..., n, where n is the number of stations - 1. I would like to associate the name of the stations with their station ID (which I recover from the database) so the `value` associated with the `<option>` node would be those IDs. To do that, I suppose I would need to push the name of the stations at the index of the corresponding ID. I have tried doing that with the following modifications to `getStationList()`:

```
function getStationList($regions)
{
    $slt_nomStations = (isset($_GET["slt_nomStations"]) ? $_GET["slt_nomStations"] : 0);;
    $db = ConnectionFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT S.station_id, S.name, SA.sub_area_name FROM dev.Station AS S INNER JOIN dbo.SubArea AS SA ON S.sub_area_id = SA.sub_area_id INNER JOIN data.MonthlyNormalData as MND ON MND.station_id = S.station_id WHERE sub_area_name = '$regions[$slt_nomStations]' AND value IS NOT NULL ORDER BY S.name ASC");
    $stmt->execute();

    $IDs = array();
    $names = array();
    $stations = array();
    $lastStationName = "";
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
        if ($lastStationName != $row['name'])
        {
            array_push($names, $row['name']);
            array_push($IDs, $row['station_id']);

            $lastStationName = $row['name'];
        }
    }

    $stations = array_fill_keys($IDs, $names);

    $newJSArray = json_encode($stations);
    echo json_encode($newJSArray);
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work since the output of the `getStationList()` function is now something like this: `"{\"6047\":[\"LA GRANDE RIVIERE A\"]}"`. So how would I have to modify my code for it to generate my `<select>` node with its children `<option>` nodes having their `value` attribute set to the ID of each of their corresponding station names?

Comment: Don't call `json_encode()` on the result of calling `json_encode`.

Comment: @Barmar If I don't, I get the following error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character`, which is at the following line: `stationsList = JSON.parse({"6047":"LA GRANDE RIVIERE A"});`. Not calling `json_encode()` a second on the result of called `json_encode()' makes the output of the function `getStationList()` `{"6047":"LA GRANDE RIVIERE A"}` instead of `"{\"6047\":[\"LA GRANDE RIVIERE A\"]}"`

Comment: Ahh, that's because you're calling `JSON.parse()` unnecessarily in the Javascript. Inserting the result of `getStationList()` parses it automatically, and then you parse it again. Get rid of **both** these extra encodes and parses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not something like

```
$arr = array()
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
     $arr[$row['stationID']] = $row['stationName'];
}
```

You're using array_push, which doesn't let you specify a key for the pushed value - you'll just get the next higher available index. So don't use the array_*() functions, and just stuff in your key/value pairs directly.

Comment: I just tried this solution, and it outputs the same `"{\"6047\":[\"LA GRANDE RIVIERE A\"]}"` as the way I have done it initially. When I debug the code, the problem seems to be at `for (var x=0; x < obj.length; x++)` where it does not go in that for to create the `<option>` nodes (my combobox is empty).

Comment: you can't use a for loop if your keys aren't sequential. you need a `for (var i in arr)` loop

Comment: It now works when I modified `for (var x=0; x < obj.length; x++)` for `for (var x in obj)`, unfortunately now I am stuck with extra `<option>` nodes in all of my `<select>` comboboxes that contain function names as `value` attribute and the function implementation between the `<option>` and `</option>` tags. Is there a way to get rid of them? This seems to be caused because the for goes and get the values in the `_proto_` as well as in the "regular" indexes of the array (found that out while debugging).

Comment: If it can help, the comboboxes that are displaying this behavior are of type [object Array], while the one that is ok (the station combobox which I tried your solution on) is of type [object Object] in the debugger.

Comment: a jquery `$.each()` may be better then, it knows to skip "internal" things.